# .NET Core reference to project which is not built to default location

Tags: visual-studio-2015, reference, .net-core

I'm new to .NET Core and referencing in MS projects, I'm hoping someone can help with this.

I have a new .NET Core application running on .NET Framework 4.6 in Visual Studio 2015 (we cannot upgrade to 2017, currently).

I am trying to reference an existing .NET class library from within this project. I have managed to reference the class library by updating the **project.json** like so:

```
"frameworks": {
  "net46": {
    "dependencies": {
      "ExistingClassLib": {
        "target": "project"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The issue is when I try to build I get an error as the existing class library is not configured to build to the default build directory and .NET Core is trying to find the DLL's there:

```
error : D:\Development\NewApplication\error CS0006: Metadata file 'D:\Development\ExistingClassLib\bin\Debug\ExistingClassLib.dll' could not be found
```

I assumed the .NET Core application would look for the DLL in the location the Output Path was set to in the ExistingClassLib settings, but it appears not.

Any ideas how I can get it to find the ExistingClassLib DLL?

Comment: Are you able to use the csproj system instead of the project.json system?